# Javascript - Pause user scrolling when user reaches a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a page that displays different types of media, images and videos primarily. I want to be able to pause the user from scrolling to far and past the media. What I mean is, I want the media to be dead center in the screen, so a user comes to the page, and begins scrolling down to the next media object, when that media object is dead center in the screen, I want to prevent the user from scrolling any further, for just a second, so that they dont scroll to far.

I have tried the example from https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-scroll-snap-using-css--cms-30333

However, it only appears to work for the first div one time...

Here is my code

```css
.scroll-snappers,
.snapit {
  height: fit-content;
}

.scroll-snappers {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.snapit {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ckrack/scrollsnap-polyfill/develop/dist/scrollsnap-polyfill.bundled.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-snappers">
  <div class="snapit">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iNku1gA.jpg" height="500" />
  </div>
  <div class="snapit">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iNku1gA.jpg" height="500" />
  </div>
  <div class="snapit">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iNku1gA.jpg" height="500" />
  </div>
  <div class="snapit">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iNku1gA.jpg" height="500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could make it work by adding the `overflow:scroll;` and `height:90vh;` css properties to the `.scroll-snappers`

```css
.scroll-snappers {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

https://codepen.io/gui3/pen/rNNbVwv

It seems that the scrolling element (wich was **html** instead of **.scroll-snappers**) HAS to be the same with the `scroll-snap-type` property

interesting topic

---

**edit**

easier solution :

```css
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```